# Python: Running multiple timers simultaneously

Tags: python, timer, multiple-instances

I want to create multiple timers in a loop. When the loop terminates, there should be multiple timers running. If any of the timers times out, it should call another function. 
How do I implement this in Python?
Any help will be appreciated.

eg.

```
for i in (0,6):
   do something
   start timer_i

for i in (0,6):
   if timer_i times out:
       call another function
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a timer?  Why would you need a loop to check for a timer timing out?

Comment: By timer I mean stopwatch kind of object. That loop is just an example depicting that I want to call a function whenever each of the timers times out.

Comment: All you need is to store the time when it started and check how much time has elapsed. Check the module 'time'.

Answer (score 2):

Look into `Timer`, which is locate in the  `threading` module of the python standard library. The documentation gives the following example:

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```